# PHP/MySQL - Create weekly report

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with a row timestamp and a row value.
I want to calculate all values by 7 days.

How can i make that PHP starts with first date in db and create the weekly summary?

My timeformat is dd-mm-yy.

My query is:

```
$kcl = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tick GROUP BY date ORDER BY id DESC");
```

I think it can be done with a for loop & counter, and i must make a query to find out the first records date, collect 7 days and then make the next 7 days. So i want to display the result in this layout:

```
WEEK 30.12.13-05.01.2014    |    RESULT OF CALC
WEEK 06.01.2014-12.01.204   |    RESULT OF CALC
etc.
```

I hope somebody can give me a hint.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
"SELECT *, AVG(value) AS value_avg FROM `tick` GROUP BY WEEK(date) ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Date time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Group by: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ongoing process, you should look into cron. It is an automated process that will execute a script on a set schedule that you can change, add to, etc when you want. If you have hosting it should be within your control panel options.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Not sure if this is what you want, but it maybe a step in the right direction regarding time functions in PHP.

```
<?php
    function dates_range($date1, $date2) {
       if ($date1<$date2) {
           $dates_range[]=$date1; 
           $date1=strtotime($date1); 
           $date2=strtotime($date2); 
           while ($date1!=$date2){
               $date1=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $date1), date("d", $date1)+1, date("Y", $date1)); 
               $dates_range[]=date('Y-m-d', $date1); 
           }
       }
       return $dates_range;
    }

    $date_1 = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time());
    $date_2 = 'Search 7 days on either side';
    //then compare your MySQL data to the output or through a foreach or whichever
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(dates_range($date_1, $date_2));
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: But this does not answer my question. For a cronjob i would need too a query which create the datas.
Also i dont want to make a cronjob for this, because it should be easy possible to create dynamic reports. I dont see a good reason for a cronjob in my case.

Comment: Set it so every week each you take all new data from the db and put it in a text file (your summary). Then you can UPDATE a column in the db to show that those rows have been summarized already (change their enum column from 0 to 1). Next week you query all rows that have a enum value of 0 and put them into a new text file.

Comment: I think we speak of past each other.

Comment: I mean, i want filter & calc values which was from monday-sunday and show it like:
WEEK 1   |   RESULT
WEEK 2   |   RESULT

I know how to calc, the only thing i dont know is how i can make that my php script makes dynamic filtering based on weeks from data beginning to data ending.

Answer (score 0):

I have painful ideas that may not work, but I would try:

```
$kcl = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM  where created_dt BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL $var     DAY AND SYSDATE() tick GROUP BY date ORDER BY id DESC");
```

I would have a view somewhere to edit $var to be 7,14,21, etc...

oh man...

Answer (score 0):

> I think it can be done with a for loop & counter

Yes, but why? Except in some very unusual edge cases, it's much more efficient to do data selection and aggregation in the DBMS.

Assuming you want the date to refer to the first day of the week, and assuming that your week starts on a Monday, then...

```
SELECT CONCATENATE(DATE_FORMAT(weekstart, '%d.%m.%y')
   , '-' , DATE_FORMAT(weekstart + INTERVAL 6 DAY, '%d.%m.%y') AS week,
   total
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(yourdate - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(yourdate,1) DAY) AS weekstart,
      SUM(yourvalue) AS total
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY DATE(yourdate - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(yourdate,1) DAY)
) AS ilv
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. yourdate should get replaced with my table name, or with something other?